# How can I do "Integrate the Audience Network SDK into your app" on facebook for developers in the expo environment?

Tags: react-native, expo

I start by creating a project with expo init. I recently succeeded in making an app and would like to put a facebook ad here.
I have solved many things for a long time, such as referring to expo facebookAds.

1.In facebook asset management -> Finish setting up your Android app ->Integrate the Audience Network SDK into your app
I can't solve this part.